# Erro in sin function for python

Tags: function, trigonometry

I have a question regarding using the sine function. When I entered the number 4, 8, .., etc., really I supposed to get the number somewhere very close to zero, but not exactly (Ex. 0.001, 0.0003, etc). However, I got the number y = 1.224 when x = 4, and y = -2.449 when x = 8. This should be incorrect. I don’t understand the problem here. Does anyone know what is going on here?

**[Photo of my code and a sin graph - Link]**
https://ibb.co/6YCWW90

**[Code]**

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [math.sin(0.25 * math.pi * i) for i in x]
print(y)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

Answer (score 1):

Everything works.

When i is 0, then "0.25 * math.pi * i" is precisely 0 and when you calculate the sine, you get exactly 0.0.

When i is 4, then calculating "0.25 * math.pi * i" results in a number very close to PI, but the accuracy is limited.  If you calculate the sine, you get a number which is very, very close to zero, but because of limited accuracy, not exactly zero.  The result is 1.2246467991473532e-16.  NOTE: it is 0.00000000000000012246467991473532, not 1.224 what your wrote in your question.

Similarly rounding errors result in -2.4492935982947064e-16 for i equal to 8. The argument is not exactly 2 PI and rounding errors result in a value slightly different than 0.0.
Again -2.4492935982947064e-16 is -0.00000000000000024492935982947064 and not -2.449 as you wrote in your question.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: Since it is a finite-precision floating-point number, `math.pi` != π. For more suitable results, check whether Python, or a suitable Python library, offers a `sinpi` function. With that available you then can write `sinpi(0.25*i)` for better accuracy.